# Sharp whining noise coming from rear of the car

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, noise, vitz

In my Toyota Vitz 2007, I hear a sharp whining noise coming from the rear of the vehicle.

This noise does not always happen. When the vehicle is started, the noise is not there. But after driving for 15 - 20 minutes, the noise starts. The noise is more apparent when the car is stopped. Also, it gets reduced (sometimes stops) when in parking gear.

The problem seems to be similar to the problem described in [this](http://www.scoobynet.com/general-technical-10/228596-high-pitched-whining-noise-from-rear-of-car.html) thread. The cause for the problem in that thread was the fuel pump.

My fuel pump got damaged during a cleanup and I had to replace the pump housing. The electric motor was not replaced. The noise was there before the replacement and the noise is still there.

What could be the cause of this noise?

If it is the fuel pump, do I have to replace it?

Comment: There are not many components on the rear of the vehicle. I'm almost certain the issue is the fuel pump. An interesting observation: you had the noise previously but fuel pump housing was replaced without replacing the electric motor. Why?

Comment: @juhist the pump housing was replaced because the carbon canister blew up when the mechanic tried to clean it using compressed air

Comment: I don't know where the charcoal canister might be, but there may be an issue with it venting incorrectly. I'd suggest the possibility of the fuel tank pressure also leaking out, but I think the OBDII system would catch this.

Comment: Your charcoal canister might be located under the car just behind the gas tank. Check those connections for a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

Classic fuel pump issue. Replace it. 
What's most likely to have happened is one or two of the little vanes in the pump has snapped off on a piece of rust/dirt. This makes that whine, particularly once the pump reaches full pressure and warms up a bit.